# Represent an integer as a sum of n non-consecutive squares

Tags: sums-of-squares

Is it possible to decompose an integer into a sum of n unique squares ,even though they are not necessarily consecutive.

For instance, How would I obtain the sequence 1*1 + 7*7 + 14*14 + 37*37 given the integer 1615
or 11*11 + 15*15 + 29*29 + 43*43 + 69*69 given the integer 7797.

Comment: Not if the integer is 2, 3, 6, 7, ..., assuming “unique” means pairwise distinct.

Comment: The question is vague: is $n$ a fixed number (like $5$ in GH from MO's answer)?  What does consecutive have to do with the problem?

Comment: One might say consecutive has nothing to do with the problem.  Unfortunately, neither answer addresses the nonconsecutive aspect, focussing instead on no repeated summands.  I assume the post disallows sums that include e.g. 2209 and 2304 as members of the same sum.

Answer (score 8):

[OEIS A001422](http://oeis.org/A001422) gives the full list of
natural numbers not expressible as the sum of distinct squares:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 
\\
43, 44, 47, 48, 60, 67, 72, 76, 92, 96, 108, 112, 128.
\end{array}
$$
The reference is

> R. Sprague, Über Zerlegungen in ungleiche Quadratzahlen, 
>   *Math. Z.* **51** (1948), 289$-$290.

(This [two-page paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0051&DMDID=DMDLOG_0025)
is several decades before Halter-Koch 1982, which concerns
decompositions into exactly $5$ distinct squares.)

*Added later*: The Sprague paper is elementary and constructive,
thus also answering the OP's question "*How* would I obtain
[a sum-of-distinct-squares representation] given the integer".
Basically, starting from $n$, subtract the first square larger than $n/2$,
and repeat until you first reach a number less than $300$.
That number will still exceed $128$, so to finish consult
a table with a distinct-square representation of each of the 
integers in $(128,300)$.  Such a table was routine to compute
even in 1948, and is basically trivial with the computer.

For example, applying this technique to the OP's $1615$ yields
$1615 = 29^2 + 20^2 + 14^2 + 178$, and then for instance $178 = 13^2 + 3^2$
or $178 = 12^2 + 5^2 + 3^2$.

If we read "even though they are not consecutive" in the strict sense 
that *no* pair of consecutive squares is allowed in the sum, then
much the same technique must still work, though with thresholds
somewhat larger than $128$ and $300$, and subtracting from $n$ 
the smallest $k$ such that $n-k^2 < (k-1)^2$ (not just less than $k^2$).

Comment: Knowing Halter-Koch, one can of course easily recover this list; e.g. in **gp**:
$$ $$
**P = prod(m=1,15,1+q^(m^2),1+O(q^246)); for(n=1,245,if(polcoeff(P,n)==0,print(n)))**

Comment: Yes, the last technique is ore or less what Thompson and I did with odd squares in our paper: subtract off the largest possible odd square until you get into a low range where you can check everything case by case.

Comment: But that can't tell you that at most $11$ squares suffice;
you must have given some other argument to obtain that result.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was being a little loose: Pall proved in AMM in 1933 that every integer which is 4 (mod 8) and greater than 412 is a sum of 4 distinct odd squares, and we use that as a starting point to show that between 4 and 11 distinct odd squares work for any integer (obviously depending on its congruence (mod 8) ). We also used a 1955 result of Schinzel about sums of 3 squares. –

Comment: I should say that as far as the character-theoretic application was concerned, the fact that the number of odd squares was at most 11 was not really necessary- any number would have done, as long as they were distinct odd squares. –

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by [Lagrange's four-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem). More generally, for any $k$ there is an $s$ such that any natural number is the sum of $s$ $k$-th powers, see [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem).

**Added 1.** Halter-Koch proved in 1982 that any integer greater than 245 is the sum of 5 *distinct* squares, see Satz 4 [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa42/aa4212.pdf). He also determined which numbers are not the sum of 4 *distinct* squares (there infinitely many exceptions, but only finitely many exceptions that are not divisible by 4), see Satz 3 [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa42/aa4212.pdf).

**Added 2.** For representability as a sum of more distinct squares, see the paper by Bateman, Hildebrand, Purdy [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf). For example, Table I in this paper tells us that any integer greater than 343296 is the sum of 100 *distinct* squares.

**Added 3.** It is straightforward to show that for any $d>0$, every sufficiently large $n$ is the sum of squares of 5 natural numbers whose minimal distance is at least $d$. This is because, by the circle method, the number of representations $n=n_1^2+\dots +n_5^2$ is $\gg n^{3/2}$, while the number of representations with $|n_i-n_j|<d$ for some $1\leq i<j\leq 5$ is $\ll_{d,\epsilon} n^{1+\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of *uniqueness*.

Comment: hmm, does that answer the OP's question for any $n$?

Comment: @Carlo: It was not clear if $n$ is given, or we can choose it.

Comment: @Noah: See my added section.

Comment: Ooh, neat, I didn't know about Halter-Koch! (Citation: I believe this is the paper "Darstellung naturlicher Zahlen als S{\''u}mmen von Quadraten" in Acta Arithmetica, 1982.)

Comment: @Noah: I added a link to the paper.

Comment: Your comment on infinitely many not the sum of $4$ distinct squares puzzled me a bit.  But I see that this is just because of the obstruction from powers of $2$ (Satz 3 in the paper).

Comment: @Lucia: That's right.

Comment: The reference to Bateman, Hildebrand, Purdy reminded me of a paper by Montgomery and Vorhauer, which you might also find interesting.  The paper is: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-245/S0025-5718-03-01513-8/S0025-5718-03-01513-8.pdf

Comment: @Lucia: Thank you very much!

Comment: Small point: The number of representations by a quatenary form may grow like $\sigma(n)$, so you should probably put $\ll_d n^{1+\epsilon}$ for the number of representations with $|n_i-n_j|<d$.

Comment: @Lucia: Thank you! (I have already fixed this before your comment.)

Answer (score 3):

John Thompson and I proved in a paper about character theory of the Alternating group that for $m > 1922$, it is possible to express $m$ as a sum of at most $11$ distinct odd squares.

Comment: Thus, non-consecutive.

Comment: Any thoughts on how many such representations a number s could have?

Comment: I expect quite a lot as $n$ gets larger, but I don't have a formal proof of that.

Comment: See my "Added 3" section.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer, but I suspect for every n greater than 3, all but finitely many
positive integers will have a representation as a sum of n distinct and
nonconsecutive squares, and of those, only finitely many will have only one such
representation.

Here is a method to search for a representation.  Given integers n and s, you know
that if there is a representation, the largest summand is greater than s/n.  Now
for each square q from s/n to some limit less than s, consider the subproblem
(s-q, n-1, q), which is to represent s-q as the sum of n-1 distinct and nonconsecutive
squares, all less than the largest square less than q.  A program which searches for such
representations and values of n less than 10 should be able to find one or more
representations when they exist for s less than a billion quite quickly.  You may find
a good upper bound for non representable numbers fairly quickly, and from that
conjecture a general bound depending only on n greater than 3.

Comment: See my "Added 3" section.